# Filter CSV file with powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I am new to powershell ... I am trying to filter one of my scan result (.csv) on specific value, I am able to do this for simple CSV files. however the automated scan result seems like nested.

I need to filter Column "F" where the value is "Vuln" (Image is added) and write to a new CSV file.

can anyone please give me some leads.

I tried simple lines like : (but I didnt get any result)

> Import-CSV -Path "C:\test.csv" | Where-Object {$_.Type -ey"Vuln"}

---

[Sample CSV file format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAGv0.jpg)

Comment: [An image of your code is not helpful](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) - that is also valid for all kinds of sample data. ... and you have a typo in your code `-ey` ->  `-eq`

Comment: If your data is not valid CSV you cannot expect Powershell to gracefully deal with it. You will have to transform your source data to fit your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mostly there, it looks like problem is coming from that `.CSV` file.

Frankly, it isn't a truly valid csv file, since it isn't just a simple Comma Separated Value sheet, instead it has multiple types of data.

However, it looks like something close to a real .CSV begins on line 6, so what we'll need to do is skip the first few rows of the file and *then* try to convert from .csv.  I made my own .csv like yours

[image]

I can read the file and skip the first five lines like so:

```
Get-Content C:\temp\input.csv | Select-Object -Skip 5 | ConvertFrom-Csv 
HostName  OS    Type   
--------  --    ----   
SomePC123 WinXp Vuln   
SomePC234 Win7  Vuln   
SomePc345 Win10 Patched
```

And then filter down to just items of `Type` `Vuln` with this command:

```
Get-Content C:\temp\input.csv | Select-Object -Skip 5 | ConvertFrom-Csv | Where-Object Type -eq 'Vuln'

HostName  OS    Type
--------  --    ----
SomePC123 WinXp Vuln
SomePC234 Win7  Vuln
```

To use this, just count down the number of lines until the spreadsheet begins within your `.CSV` and edit the `-Skip` parameter to match.

If you want to keep the header information, you can use an approach like this one:

```
$crap = Get-Content C:\temp\input.csv | Select-Object -First 5
$OnlyVulns = Get-Content C:\temp\input.csv | Select-Object -Skip 5 | ConvertFrom-Csv | Where-Object Type -eq 'Vuln'

$CrapAndOnlyVulns = $crap + $OnlyVulns
$CrapAndOnlyVulns > C:\pathTo\NewFile.csv
```

Comment: Thanks Mate... it worked...i can able to sort the data.... however the newly created CSV (Output) is doesn't contain that skipped data ....  Is there any way we can included that too after processing? just checking possibility.

Comment: Thank you.. It worked, however the output csv was scrambled (the second part, combined in singled row and columns), I did some modifications.. now it is perfect... Thank you Very much.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final script :)

> $import = get-content .\Scan.csv
>   $import1= $import | Select-Object -First 7
>   $import | Select-Object -Skip 7 | ConvertFrom-Csv | Where-Object {$_.Type -eq "Vuln"} | Export-Csv Output1.csv -NoClobber -NoTypeInformation
>   $import1 + (Get-Content Output1.csv) | Set-Content Output2.csv